# Class diagram for big data batch processing

Tags: db2, bigdata, batch-processing, cobol, class-diagram

I am a beginner in cobol, and I'm passing an internship in big data batch processing, I am asked to do a class diagram in my project, but I have no classes, I only have tables with millions of records in DB2 that are being processed with cobol language, my question is : is it possible to make a class diagram in this situation ? (forigve my english)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is entirely possible. An entity-relationship diagram of a database model is practically a class diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Class diagrams are used with OOP languages. I am not sure how far did OO-COBOL go, but I have a feeling that it is not a common practice to use it in batch processing. Batch processing has always been mainly accomplished with NON-OO COBOL in COBOL shops or using C, C++ or JAVA on mainframes and UNIX, of course you could use any other suitable technology...

Class diagram shows classes (no corresponding non-oo COBOL structure for that)  and associations between them. If each class represents 1 physical table and no OO features such as inheritance, a class diagram may be very close to an Entity Relationship diagram. However, a class is a code file in OO (or part of a code file) but in non OO-COBOL, a class does not exist and database columns are coded inside the some program of some name that is never shown on the Entity Relationship diagram.